# Compiler can't find SDL?

Tags: c++, command-line, compiler-construction, sdl

[The instructions I found to install SDL2](https://users.cs.jmu.edu/bernstdh/web/common/help/cpp_mingw-sdl-setup.php) said I had to copy some files into the MinGW file. I had done as instructed, then double and triple checked and still no luck.

This is the error I get when I try and compile it using the command line:

```
E:\Roguelike\g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -lSDL2 -lSDLmain sdltest.cpp -o sdltest
e:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot fin
d -lSDLmain
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

E:\Roguelike\
```

I have tried compiling a normal test program that doesn't use SDL and it works so I know the compiler is working properly.

I have also noticed that when I go to copy the bin, lib, include files into the MinGW folder, there are multiple options. Maybe I used the wrong one?

In the SDL2-2.0.3 folder there are files called "i686-w64-mingw32","x86_64-w64-mingw32","include","lib" and "test". I tried all of them and still can't see what the problem is. Maybe a bug in SDL 2.0.3?

I must be doing something wrong so can someone guide me through what I have to do to install SDL2 properly for MinGW 4.8.1?

If it is installed properly maybe I'm compiling it wrong?

Comment: yes that is what apparently is missing when it actually is there if that is what you mean

Comment: What? I'm simply saying that in your post above you have `SDLmain` (without the 2). It should be `SDL2main`.

Comment: ah I see what you mean, I tried that too and now I am getting a different type of error along the lines of *path to somewhere in appdata* unidentified reference to 'SDL_Init'

Answer (score 1):

The fourth step of the installation guide you linked to:

> When you link, you must link-in SDL2main.a and SDL2.a using -lSDL2main
>   and -lSDL2

Try that and it should work, given that you didn't deviate from the guide in any other way too.

Comment: g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -lSDL2 -lSDLmain sdltest.cpp -o sdltest
this is the command I use to compile it

Comment: @thejason And that's most likely what's causing your problems. Try changing `-lSDL2 -lSDLmain` for `-lSDL2main -lSDL2`. As I recall the order matters and -lSDL2main should come before -lSDL2